# import com.itextpdf.pdfoffice.OfficeConverter doesnt work

Tags: java, spring-boot, itext

`com.itextpdf.pdfoffice.OfficeConverter` doesn't work. Can anyone tell me how to convert Pdf to Word (.doc/ .docx) using Java?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
import com.itextpdf.pdfoffice.OfficeConverter;

import java.io.File;

public class ItextPdfOfficeWordToPdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //LicenseKey.loadLicenseFile(new File("license.json"));
        File pdfOutFile = new File("out_office.pdf");
        File demoFile = new File("/home/wdq/下载/2022年重庆市博士后科学基金项目申报书1-正文.docx");
        OfficeConverter.convertOfficeDocumentToPdf(demoFile, pdfOutFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't work*?

Comment: com.itextpdf.pdfoffice.OfficeConverter doesnt see library because not found   dependency in  pom.xml for itextpdfoofice. ı try <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfoffice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.3</version>
        </dependency> but doesnt work

Comment: Have you added the iText maven repository to your configuration?

Comment: yes but com.itextpdf.pdfoffice doesnt support

Comment: What do you mean by *doesn't support*?